# Why does the WebViewDemo die?

Tags: android

I copied [this WebViewDemo demo](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java) **verbatim** from the official Google site.

Yet, the moment I click on that little Android image, the application dies (instead of making raise its hand):

```
03-09 18:57:05.001: WARN/dalvikvm(615): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x405479d0 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
03-09 18:57:05.001: INFO/dalvikvm(615): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
03-09 18:57:05.001: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4051e6e8 self=0x1e6d68
03-09 18:57:05.001: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   | sysTid=623 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1994400
03-09 18:57:05.011: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   | schedstat=( 1010445328 962770675 122 )
03-09 18:57:05.011: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
03-09 18:57:05.011: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
03-09 18:57:05.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:53)
03-09 18:57:05.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1158)
03-09 18:57:05.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 18:57:05.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-09 18:57:05.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
03-09 18:57:05.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-09 18:57:05.030: ERROR/dalvikvm(615): VM aborting
03-09 18:57:05.151: INFO/DEBUG(593): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-09 18:57:05.151: INFO/DEBUG(593): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:2.3.1/GSI11/93351:eng/test-keys'
03-09 18:57:05.161: INFO/DEBUG(593): pid: 615, tid: 623  >>> com.google.android.webviewdemo <<<
03-09 18:57:05.161: INFO/DEBUG(593): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
03-09 18:57:05.161: INFO/DEBUG(593):  r0 fffffebc  r1 deadd00d  r2 00000026  r3 00000000
03-09 18:57:05.161: INFO/DEBUG(593):  r4 81da45c8  r5 405479d0  r6 81d859ec  r7 001e7770
03-09 18:57:05.161: INFO/DEBUG(593):  r8 43625b54  r9 42dd1e4c  10 42dd1e34  fp 4168d82c
03-09 18:57:05.161: INFO/DEBUG(593):  ip 81da4728  sp 43625348  lr afd19375  pc 81d45a02  cpsr 20000030
03-09 18:57:05.370: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #00  pc 00045a02  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-09 18:57:05.370: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #01  pc 000376fc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-09 18:57:05.370: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #02  pc 000399c4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-09 18:57:05.370: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #03  pc 0003a4a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-09 18:57:05.380: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #04  pc 0032b6e6  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.380: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #05  pc 002a4db4  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.392: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #06  pc 001a6146  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.392: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #07  pc 002a5880  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.392: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #08  pc 00359e5e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.401: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #09  pc 0035d1b6  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.401: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #10  pc 0036b0a0  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.411: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #11  pc 003627d8  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.411: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #12  pc 0029fb34  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.421: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #13  pc 0023368e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.421: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #14  pc 00239c1c  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.431: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #15  pc 00237a38  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.431: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #16  pc 00237b42  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.431: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #17  pc 0023adca  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.440: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #18  pc 0023af5e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.440: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #19  pc 000f80c8  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.450: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #20  pc 000f8c6e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.450: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #21  pc 001b820a  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.461: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #22  pc 001b8302  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.461: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #23  pc 001b8328  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
03-09 18:57:05.471: INFO/DEBUG(593):          #24  pc 00017d34  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-09 18:57:05.471: INFO/DEBUG(593): code around pc:
03-09 18:57:05.471: INFO/DEBUG(593): 81d459e0 447a4479 ed0cf7d1 20004c09 ee34f7d1 
03-09 18:57:05.471: INFO/DEBUG(593): 81d459f0 447c4808 6bdb5823 d0002b00 49064798 
03-09 18:57:05.471: INFO/DEBUG(593): 81d45a00 700a2226 eea0f7d1 0004361f 000451dd 
03-09 18:57:05.471: INFO/DEBUG(593): 81d45a10 0005ebd2 fffffebc deadd00d b510b40e 
03-09 18:57:05.480: INFO/DEBUG(593): 81d45a20 4c0a4b09 447bb083 aa05591b 6b5bca02 
03-09 18:57:05.480: INFO/DEBUG(593): code around lr:
03-09 18:57:05.480: INFO/DEBUG(593): afd19354 b0834a0d 589c447b 26009001 686768a5 
03-09 18:57:05.490: INFO/DEBUG(593): afd19364 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901 
03-09 18:57:05.490: INFO/DEBUG(593): afd19374 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee 
03-09 18:57:05.490: INFO/DEBUG(593): afd19384 bdf01c30 000281a8 ffffff88 1c0fb5f0 
03-09 18:57:05.490: INFO/DEBUG(593): afd19394 43551c3d a904b087 1c16ac01 604d9004 
03-09 18:57:05.490: INFO/DEBUG(593): stack:
03-09 18:57:05.500: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625308  00000015  
03-09 18:57:05.500: INFO/DEBUG(593):     4362530c  afd18407  /system/lib/libc.so
03-09 18:57:05.500: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625310  afd4270c  /system/lib/libc.so
03-09 18:57:05.500: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625314  afd426b8  /system/lib/libc.so
03-09 18:57:05.500: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625318  00000000  
03-09 18:57:05.500: INFO/DEBUG(593):     4362531c  afd19375  /system/lib/libc.so
03-09 18:57:05.512: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625320  001e6d68  [heap]
03-09 18:57:05.512: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625324  afd183d9  /system/lib/libc.so
03-09 18:57:05.512: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625328  001e7770  [heap]
03-09 18:57:05.512: INFO/DEBUG(593):     4362532c  0005ebd2  [heap]
03-09 18:57:05.521: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625330  405479d0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
03-09 18:57:05.521: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625334  81d859ec  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-09 18:57:05.521: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625338  001e7770  [heap]
03-09 18:57:05.521: INFO/DEBUG(593):     4362533c  afd18437  /system/lib/libc.so
03-09 18:57:05.521: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625340  df002777  
03-09 18:57:05.521: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625344  e3a070ad  
03-09 18:57:05.521: INFO/DEBUG(593): #00 43625348  00000001  
03-09 18:57:05.531: INFO/DEBUG(593):     4362534c  81d37701  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-09 18:57:05.531: INFO/DEBUG(593): #01 43625350  00000001  
03-09 18:57:05.531: INFO/DEBUG(593):     43625354  81d399c9  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-09 18:57:07.720: INFO/BootReceiver(68): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_07 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-09 18:57:07.771: DEBUG/Zygote(33): Process 615 terminated by signal (11)
03-09 18:57:07.771: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Process com.google.android.webviewdemo (pid 615) has died.
03-09 18:57:07.800: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '40763638 com.google.android.webviewdemo/com.google.android.webviewdemo.WebViewDemo (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
03-09 18:57:07.800: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '40763638 com.google.android.webviewdemo/com.google.android.webviewdemo.WebViewDemo (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-09 18:57:07.942: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_CONCURRENT freed 987K, 50% free 4275K/8455K, external 2269K/3469K, paused 18ms+8ms
03-09 18:57:07.951: INFO/WindowManager(68): WIN DEATH: Window{40763638 com.google.android.webviewdemo/com.google.android.webviewdemo.WebViewDemo paused=false}
03-09 18:57:08.051: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 352K, 48% free 4440K/8455K, external 2269K/3469K, paused 69ms
03-09 18:57:08.251: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 531K, 50% free 4260K/8455K, external 2269K/3469K, paused 78ms
03-09 18:57:08.341: WARN/InputManagerService(68): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 615 uid 10030
```

Why? Is the bug in the demo itself? (I can't believe I am the first one to discover that) or is it a bug in my own development environment setup?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From: [phonegap.js crashes android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459458/phonegap-js-crashes-android-app)

This is a bug with 2.3.x. simulator - Javascript->Java bridge is bugged.

The Google bug specifically uses this demo code.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987

Go star it so they know to fix it soon.

You can workaround this for now by just using a 2.2 emulator.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me whether "2.2 emulator" means the emulator that came with SDK 8 or simply a 2.2 AVD. But I just tried the emulator that came with SDK 9, configured to run a 2.2 AVD, and it works! Thank you.

Comment: 3 years later and I'm running into this!

Comment: [This](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/126058/custom-event-inside-webview-doesnt-work-on-android-23) says it's emulator issue/bug, it will work fine on device 2.3.x?