# VM abortin error in android

Tags: java, android

When i move from one activity to another activity, it closes before open...
I got this error in my logcat

```
12-03 22:32:12.024: W/dalvikvm(885): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x4052e4a8 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
12-03 22:32:12.035: I/dalvikvm(885): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
12-03 22:32:12.035: I/dalvikvm(885):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4062c1e0 self=0x2c6580
12-03 22:32:12.035: I/dalvikvm(885):   | sysTid=910 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2909880
12-03 22:32:12.045: I/dalvikvm(885):   | schedstat=( 12594251910 11957404058 1074 )
12-03 22:32:12.045: I/dalvikvm(885):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeFinished(Native Method)
12-03 22:32:12.045: I/dalvikvm(885):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeFinished(Native Method)
12-03 22:32:12.055: I/dalvikvm(885):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.tearDown(LoadListener.java:1200)
12-03 22:32:12.055: I/dalvikvm(885):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleEndData(LoadListener.java:721)
12-03 22:32:12.075: I/dalvikvm(885):   at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleMessage(LoadListener.java:219)
12-03 22:32:12.075: I/dalvikvm(885):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 22:32:12.085: I/dalvikvm(885):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-03 22:32:12.085: I/dalvikvm(885):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
12-03 22:32:12.119: I/dalvikvm(885):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-03 22:32:12.119: E/dalvikvm(885): VM aborting
```

please someone help

Comment: Are you using PhoneGap in an Emulator? @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253916/why-does-the-webviewdemo-die

Comment: @shkschneider no i am not using phonegap and i dont know what is phonegap..

Comment: You need to give us more infos about your API level of your device and if it's an emulator or not. A lot of bugs occurs in WebView/WebKit android Android 2.2 for example.

Comment: @shkschneider yeah its an emulator and its api level is 10.

Comment: @JaredBurrows i want to know that its an emulator problem or error in my code?? actually this problem was not occuring before but i insert some code which is for closing some activity from anoter activity. My code is public static myactivity ma; onCreate(){ ma= this;} and in other activity myactivity.ma.finish(); is this creating a problem.

Comment: @dheeraj92 You have not given enough information for anyone to make a clear answer.

Comment: @JaredBurrows which information i have to give or what type of information you want. Please help me

Comment: You never listened to my first comment. Post the relevant code. Post an entire stacktrace, not just a JNI error. Is that even apart of your app? What are you trying to do?