# Phonegap Android app keeps crashing

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an app for android tablets using the phonegap framework.  However my app keeps crashing when going to the second page.  Here is the LogCat output:

```
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272): Build fingerprint: 'acer/picasso_generic1/picasso:3.1/HMJ37/1309327721:user/release-keys'
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272): pid: 2403, tid: 2411  >>> com.xxxxxxxx <<<
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000010
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  r0 5932a92c  r1 aff17380  r2 00000000  r3 0000003f
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  r4 005dcd18  r5 5932a910  r6 5932a92c  r7 00000000
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  r8 005dcd18  r9 00000000  10 00000000  fp 005e0040
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  ip a883f6e4  sp 5932a88c  lr a8441de3  pc a843fbd0  cpsr 60000030
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  d0  4140000000000000  d1  0000000045200000
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  3ff0000000000000
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  412c965600000000
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  d6  3ff0000000000000  d7  3f80000000000000
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
09-04 16:35:22.030: INFO/DEBUG(2272):  scr 20000013
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272):          #00  pc 00269bd0  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272):          #01  pc 0026bdde  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272):          #02  pc 0026c73e  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): libc base address: afed6000
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): code around pc:
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): a843fbb0 71f8f501 6b00ed90 7b00ed91 6bc7eeb4 
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): a843fbc0 fa10eef1 2000bf54 47702001 6802b5f0 
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): a843fbd0 bb7b6913 68956856 0701f006 08764b3e 
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): a843fbe0 46344629 f831e00b 3c01cc04 f8314463 
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): a843fbf0 ea83cc02 ea8c2ccc eb034303 310423d3 
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): code around lr:
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): a8441dc0 f207fb00 bfb8428a 46204619 fec2f7ff 
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): a8441dd0 463068a3 b000f8d4 46b92700 f7fd9303 
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): a8441de0 9903fef5 ea009504 90020a01 fb02220c 
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): a8441df0 eb0bf50a 46400805 f7ff9501 9b01fd8b 
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): a8441e00 b9f84605 0003f85b d00d1c43 46314640 
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272): stack:
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a84c  0000000c  
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a850  005dcd18  
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a854  00553310  
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a858  00000000  
09-04 16:35:22.140: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a85c  a8441c0f  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a860  005dcb60  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a864  0030cf50  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a868  00000000  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a86c  afee935b  /system/lib/libc.so
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a870  00000000  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a874  00000000  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a878  00000000  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a87c  005dcd18  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a880  df002777  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a884  e3a070ad  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a888  00553310  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272): #00 5932a88c  005dcd18  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a890  5932a910  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a894  5932a92c  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a898  00000000  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a89c  a8441de3  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272): #01 5932a8a0  0030cf50  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8a4  00000000  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8a8  fffffe90  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8ac  0000003f  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8b0  00000018  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8b4  5932a93c  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8b8  005531d8  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8bc  5932a940  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8c0  5932a92c  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8c4  00552ee0  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8c8  00553310  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8cc  005dcd18  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8d0  5932a940  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8d4  00000000  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8d8  00000001  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8dc  005dca80  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8e0  5932a92c  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8e4  5932a944  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8e8  00553310  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8ec  005dcd18  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8f0  5932a940  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8f4  00000000  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8f8  00000001  
09-04 16:35:22.150: INFO/DEBUG(2272):     5932a8fc  a8442743  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using 2.3 emulator?
It has a nasty bug related to JavaScript in WebView.

See: [phonegap.js craches android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459458/phonegap-js-crashes-android-app)