# Error: Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed! (PhoneGap)

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on PhoneGap and when I run my application I got error **Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!** and my application gets closed.
Here is my code :

```
public class DossiuerActivity extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/menu.html");
  }
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You got this error on emulator or a device ?

Comment: Hi! dhruvisa try this link it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459458/phonegap-js-crashes-android-app

Comment: @ShashankKadne i got this on emulator but also does not work on device.

Comment: super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/menu.html");, what is www?

Comment: @Tech_Droiod i gone through that link and i use 2.2 it solved. thanks.

Comment: @RobinHood its my folder name in asset folder.