# Android connect to website using HttpUrlConnection fails

Tags: java, android, web, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to connect to a webpage on my server from within an Android app I'm creating, but it seems to be failing on one line for some reason.

Java code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://redsquirrelsoftware.co.uk/android/assignments/androidlogin.php");
HttpURLConnection hConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);

hConnection.setDoOutput(true);
hConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");   

// ERROR OCCURS ON NEXT LINE
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(hConnection.getOutputStream());
ps.print("email=" + LoginActivity.email + "&" + "pword=" + LoginActivity.password);
ps.close();
hConnection.connect();
```

LogCat response is giving me an IllegalStateException - Unable to access the application key, which I have never seen before and don't know how to go about fixing it. It also mentions TimerTask.run(), which I don't have in any of my code - guessing it's some of Android's own code?

```
01-08 21:28:55.300: E/MtpService(17770): TimerTask.run(): mReason =1
01-08 21:28:57.990: E/InputDispatcher(165): channel '41621cb0 uk.co.redsquirrelsoftware.assignmenttracker/uk.co.redsquirrelsoftware.assignmenttracker.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-08 21:29:01.870: E/GetJar SDK(17935): PackageMonitor: doOnReceive(): failed
01-08 21:29:01.870: E/GetJar SDK(17935): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access the application key
01-08 21:29:01.870: E/GetJar SDK(17935):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.doOnReceive(PackageMonitor.java:113)
01-08 21:29:01.870: E/GetJar SDK(17935):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.access$000(PackageMonitor.java:62)
01-08 21:29:01.870: E/GetJar SDK(17935):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor$1.run(PackageMonitor.java:87)
01-08 21:29:01.870: E/GetJar SDK(17935):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-08 21:29:02.230: E/GetJar SDK(17918): PackageMonitor: doOnReceive(): failed
01-08 21:29:02.230: E/GetJar SDK(17918): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access the application key
01-08 21:29:02.230: E/GetJar SDK(17918):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.doOnReceive(PackageMonitor.java:117)
01-08 21:29:02.230: E/GetJar SDK(17918):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.access$000(PackageMonitor.java:59)
01-08 21:29:02.230: E/GetJar SDK(17918):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor$1.run(PackageMonitor.java:84)
01-08 21:29:02.230: E/GetJar SDK(17918):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-08 21:29:02.470: E/GetJar SDK(17918): PackageMonitor: doOnReceive(): failed
01-08 21:29:02.470: E/GetJar SDK(17918): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access the application key
01-08 21:29:02.470: E/GetJar SDK(17918):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.doOnReceive(PackageMonitor.java:117)
01-08 21:29:02.470: E/GetJar SDK(17918):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.access$000(PackageMonitor.java:59)
01-08 21:29:02.470: E/GetJar SDK(17918):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor$1.run(PackageMonitor.java:84)
01-08 21:29:02.470: E/GetJar SDK(17918):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-08 21:29:02.500: E/GetJar SDK(17935): PackageMonitor: doOnReceive(): failed
01-08 21:29:02.500: E/GetJar SDK(17935): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access the application key
01-08 21:29:02.500: E/GetJar SDK(17935):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.doOnReceive(PackageMonitor.java:113)
01-08 21:29:02.500: E/GetJar SDK(17935):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.access$000(PackageMonitor.java:62)
01-08 21:29:02.500: E/GetJar SDK(17935):    at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor$1.run(PackageMonitor.java:87)
01-08 21:29:02.500: E/GetJar SDK(17935):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-08 21:29:17.530: E/dalvikvm(18081): Could not find class 'com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaDeserializers.findCollectionDeserializer
01-08 21:29:17.540: E/dalvikvm(18081): Could not find class 'com.google.common.collect.EnumBiMap', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaDeserializers.findMapDeserializer
01-08 21:29:17.540: E/dalvikvm(18081): Could not find class 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSetMultimap', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaDeserializers.findMapLikeDeserializer
01-08 21:29:17.540: E/dalvikvm(18081): Could not find class 'com.google.common.collect.Table', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaDeserializers.findMapLikeDeserializer
```

Any suggestions on how to go about fixing it?
Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459719/why-i-am-getting-error-channel-is-unrecoverably-broken-and-will-be-disposed

Answer (score 1):

I think that the relevant line in the log is:

01-08 21:28:57.990: E/InputDispatcher(165): channel '41621cb0 uk.co.redsquirrelsoftware.assignmenttracker/uk.co.redsquirrelsoftware.assignmenttracker.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

See the accepted answer to this question:

[Error: Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed! (PhoneGap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327942/error-channel-is-unrecoverably-broken-and-will-be-disposed-phonegap)

Comment: Hmmm... I looked at that question but doesn't really help in this case. Do you know what can cause a channel to become unrecoverably broken so I can look through all my other code and see if there's something breaking it there?